# Converting string values into frequency count

Tags: r, data.table, frequency

I'm relatively new to R, and I'm struggling to reorganise a table in data.table. 
The table is currently as follows:

```
species number snow_depth
wolf      3          5
wolf      1          5
wolf      1          5
coyote    1          30
coyote    1          30
```

I'm attempting to have it set up like this instead:

```
coyote   wolf   snow depth
 0          3         5
 0          1         5
 0          1         5
 1          0        30
```

etc. 
With the view to use ggplot2 to have snow depth on the x axis, frequency count on the y axis, and 2 lines for the 2 species.

I've tried this

```
>DT %>% separate(species, c("wolf", "coyote"))
```

But instead get this output

```
     wolf coyote number snow_depth
1     wolf   <NA>      3          5
2     wolf   <NA>      1          5
3     wolf   <NA>      1          5
4   coyote   <NA>      1         30
5   coyote   <NA>      1         30
6   coyote   <NA>      1         30
7   coyote   <NA>      1         25
```

I'm also getting error messages when I input this (copied off the internet lol)

```
> separate(DT, species, sep = "[^[:alnum:]]+", remove=TRUE, convert=FALSE)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Edit - I'm getting an error using that code unfortunately. 
The plan for plotting 2 lines is that each snow depth accounts for one period in time, at which point x number of coyote and x number of wolves were recorded, so frequency of each species at each snow depth. So 2 data points for each snow depth, 1 = coyote 2 = wolf. Does that answer the question? Apologies if I've misunderstood

Comment: Hi Luna, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your example data only has one depth per species, thus, only one point per species. Could you clarify how you expect to plot a line? Perhaps provide additional data by pasting the output of `dput(DT[1:25,])` into an edit of your *original question* (not as a comment).

Comment: I don't understand your example. What exactly is the connection between your shown example data and your shown desired output? Where does the `7` came from, where did the `30` go?

Comment: Martin - apologies. I fudged making the tables, I was using fake data just to show the formatting (should have added - ignore the actual numbers!) as I have 30,000 rows of data. I’ll fix this when I’m back at keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`:

```
DT[, rn := .I]
dcast(DT, rn + snow_depth ~ species, fill=0L, value.var="number")
```

output:

```
   rn snow_depth coyote wolf
1:  1          5      0    3
2:  2          5      0    1
3:  3          5      0    1
4:  4         30      1    0
5:  5         30      1    0
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried running this, but I'm getting this error that I don't quite understand! --> 

Error in setDT(dat) : 
  All elements in argument 'x' to 'setDT' must be of same length, but the profile of input lengths (length:frequency) is: [73768:1, 10458:3]
The first entry with fewer than 73768 entries is 1

Comment: Can you share the str of your dataset?